# Unable to run mongod

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongoDB on my local machine and have set the environment variables for it.

I am able to run the mongod command anywhere inside the C:\ path.

However, when I run mongod in my folder where my nodejs file exists it shows up like this :

[image]

I'm not being able to figure out why is this happening.

Comment: Please don't paste images, provide error message as formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Just read the error message! It even gives exact instructions how to solve the error.